# Are there any LEGO base plates that are compatible with Duplo?

Tags: compatibility, duplo

I'm thinking of making a LEGO table but my two children both use different LEGO sizes. My oldest uses normal LEGO and my youngest uses DUPLO. I'm wondering if there is a base plate that both types of LEGO bricks will work on?

Answer (score 25):

A regular LEGO base plate will work with DUPLO bricks. As demonstated in [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/38/are-duplo-blocks-compatible-with-lego-blocks-in-any-way), the two systems are compatible in a number of ways. Here's an example of System base plates with DUPLO bricks attached:

[image: DUPLO on System baseplate]

It should be noted that not all DUPLO bricks will be able to connect to a System baseplate. Some examples of incompatibility are round bricks and some of the minifigs and animals. In order for these to connect you'll need a DUPLO brick or baseplate on top of the System baseplate.

Comment: How secure is this kind of connection? I'd almost think that it'd work better the other way around, with a DUPLO base and a generous amount of extra LEGO 2x4s that can be used to build a foundation for any LEGO structures. Though a look at google seems to indicate that most large DUPLO baseplates don't have the hollow pegs that allow for compatibility.

Comment: You're right - the DUPLO baseplates don't really allow System bricks to connect, while the System -> DUPLO connection is quite good.

Answer (score 4):

Regular LEGO baseplates can accommodate both LEGO and DUPLO. DUPLO obviously won't stick to regular baseplates as securely as on a DUPLO plate because the studs are much smaller, but they are compatible.

There are some pre-made LEGO tables that already have baseplates (or third-party LEGO compatible baseplates) incorporated in the top surface, or you can make your own table and cover the top with baseplates.

LEGO sells baseplates separately on their website, and they are also available at stores like Toys'R'Us. I have seen the pre-made tables at Toy'R'Us as well, and they are also available on eBay.

Comment: I would also add here that there are some excellent third-party options as well for baseplates. For example StrictlyBriks.com makes both LEGO compatible baseplates, large plates and DUPLO plates in a number of different colors, styles and shapes. These are the ones I use because they are cheaper than LEGO baseplates and come in significantly more colors. The quality is the same as LEGO. I also use them as wall-coverings for displaying minifigs and small builds.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a Nilo brick mat. It's a rubbery mat that has standard (small) lego studs on one side, and dulpo on the other. You can buy them on Amazon, Ebay or straight from Nilo. http://www.nilotoys.com/acc.htm

Comment: While I've actually seen these Nilo products, this does NOT answer the Original Poster's question.

Comment: Who ever this "gev" person is... Your comments are very rude and completely out of line. I actually found the users here to be very helpful and will be looking up the Nilo brick mat myself! They DID answer the original question and offered solutions to those of us searching.

Comment: While not meeting the request for a "baseplate" I think the Nilo Brick Mat could indeed be an answer if you're after a "one or the other" solution. That said, [System Baseplates work nicely for both sizes](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2584/56), and will out-last your DUPLO interest ;)