# How to convert LEGO base plate to a DUPLO base plate?

Tags: piece-information, compatibility, duplo

How can I convert a regular LEGO base to a DUPLO base? I have a table that cannot be changed and it has built-in LEGO baseplates, but I need it to be 100% DUPLO compatible. Any LEGO to DUPLO baseplate converters?

Comment: See also: [Are DUPLO blocks compatible with LEGO blocks in any way](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/38/56) and [Are there any LEGO baseplates that are compatible with DUPLO](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2583/56)

Answer (score 6):

The table IS already *cross* compatible, even though it doesn't look it. The tabletop or LEGO baseplate is cross molded for DUPLO pieces to fit and lock in on top of the regular LEGO baseplate.

***PART ONE: THE PICTURED PROOFS...***
[image]
So, let's imagine the top of your table is my unopened gray baseplate.

[image]
We'll use a DUPLO Cock-A-Doodle-Doo for an example DUPLO model.

[image]
Sorry, but I don't want open my baseplate just yet, so in the next four shots we'll use these green plates to show the cross interlocking magic of LEGO and DUPLO.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***PART TWO:  THE WHAT IFs...***
[image]
Now, I did say the magic was *cross* interlocking, so... *WHAT IF* your tabletop *HAD* started off DUPLO and we wanted it to be, in our minds, 100% compatible with regular LEGO.

[image]
You see, it is compatible, again, it may not look it at first glace, but as we can see using these White 2x4 LEGO bricks with a Bright Yellow 2x2 DUPLO brick things are indeed cross compatible.

[image]
I'm gonna get uber geeky here, but the harder to imagine negative space inside the White 2x4 LEGO brick interlocks beautify with the easier to see studs of the 2x2 Yellow DUPLO brick.

[image]
Well, hey!  Hoped to have saved you time, money and effort in fabricating a new table.  Later!

Comment: Thanks for the clear pictures.  They really drive your point home.

Comment: Now you have to tell us what the black, white and grey thing is. :)

Comment: A highly glorified garbage can, that's what it is!  Well, it's a trash receptacle. LEGO themed after an enemy from Super Mario World, called a Thwomp. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yxr5WEYJ-6s.