# Why doesn't lego make many 2x2x4 Pieces?

Tags: piece-information

I'm just wondering if anybody here knows where I can get some 2x2x4 pieces ... It seems that Lego doesn't make many just standard bricks that are 4 high ... I've found a few singles here and there on Ebay, but these don't exit in the pick a brick store and they are reeeally hard to find. Looking for about 16 Dark Stone Gray 2x2x4 pieces ... any leads? Or any idea why they don't make standard bricks that are 4 high? I assume it's because you can easily stack to 2 highs, but for cosmetic reasons I can't do this in my build. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all the responses ... very interesting about using Duplo blocks ... never thought of that. My only concern is that I need the sharp edges of Lego blocks for this build ... if I'm remembering correctly from my childhood, do Duplo blocks have more rounded edges? I've found a bunch of what are being advertised as 2x2x4 blocks on ebay ... try searching "2x2x4 lego brick" are these people simply incorrect and they are actually 2x2x3, or are these just rare pieces from specific kits? Thanks!

Comment: The pictures I see on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X2x2x4+lego+brick.TRS0&_nkw=2x2x4+lego+brick&ghostText=&_sacat=0) are 2x2x3 bricks being advertised as 2x2x4. Not sure if the "x4" is perhaps marketing speak for the fact that there are 4 studs on the top, but they are clearly (also visible on the picture) only 3 bricks high.

Comment: Oh and note that some use the deceiving perspective of putting a brick flat to show that it covers 4 studs on a base-plate, but that doesn't mean that they are also 4 bricks high as the width to height ratio for a LEGO brick is not 1:1.

Comment: What's wrong with stacking up 2x2x1 bricks to make the column?

Answer (score 6):

I can't find any evidence that a 2x2x4 piece has ever existed. Bricklink identifies a [2x2x3 brick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30145), and there are many sellers around the world that will happily sell you [16 dark stone grey pieces for pennies/piece](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?colorID=85&itemID=353&qMin=16).

Answer (score 4):

Another option you might want to consider is looking at [1x2x2 DUPLO](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4066) pieces. They correspond to 4x2x4 lego pieces (slightly bigger than you are asking for, but not knowing the details of your build you might be able to incorporate these) and they interconnect (a 2x2 lego piece fits on a single DUPLO stud.) If you mount them sideways you get a 2x4 surface (but it would be 4 deep, not 2 deep as you requested). 
EDIT: [This post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/38/are-duplo-blocks-compatible-with-lego-blocks-in-any-way) shows how DUPLO and LEGO play together :)

Answer (score 1):

As odd Todd mentioned LEGO never made 2x2x4 pieces. The largest brick of similar size is 2x2x3 and 2x4x3. For larger smooth surfaces LEGO usually uses panels. You can find all the panels LEGO ever made here: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=91

Comment: Just note that there is no 2x4 panel either .... 2x3 is the biggest.